# Perl - file reading - got "GLOB"

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a simple text file.
After reading the whole file into an array or only the first line into a variable when I try to use it and print out the value read text I get the following results:

```perl
GLOB(0x1234567)
```

I tried to read the whole file:

```perl
open(my $fh,'<','/path/to/file.txt') or die "Can't open data";
@lines = <$fh>;
close($fh);

print @lines;
#Results in a single "GLOB(0x1234567)" line
```

Or reading the file line by line:

```perl
open(my $fh,'<','/path/to/file.txt') or die "Can't open data";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    print $line;
    #Results in a single "GLOB(0x1234567)" line
}
close($fh);
```

The file has proper permissions, proper encoding (is UTF-8 ok?).

I think maybe it is an environment related issue because if I create a completely empty Perl script with only the lines mentioned above, the file reading works.

Comment: _"if I create a completely empty Perl script with only the lines mentioned above, the file reading works."_ - so how are we supposed to know what the problem is without seeing more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is you forgetting the `<` `>`:

```
my $line = $fh;   # wrong
my @lines = $fh;  # wrong
```

Better:

```
my $line = <$fh>;   # reads a line
my @lines = <$fh>;  # reads all lines
```

Alternatively, you might have done one of the following things:

```
my $line = <$ fh>;  # parses as glob($fh), not readline($fh)
my $line = <${fh}>;  # also means glob($fh)
my $line = <$handles[$i]>;  # glob($handles[$i])
```

Basically, if you're using `<foo>` where `foo` is anything but a dollar sign immediately followed by an identifier and nothing else, it is treated as a `glob` operation, not a `readline`.

Best solution:

```
my $line = readline $fh;
my @lines = readline $fh;
```

I like the last version best because

1. `readline` isn't syntactically overloaded like `<` `>` is, so the code is unambiguous.
2. `readline` tells you what it does: It reads a line (or a list of lines).
3. It's harder to accidentally omit.

Comment: Confusingly, the other operation performed by `<>` is `glob()`, which is completely unrelated to the `GLOB` type used by filehandles, though both of them like asterisks.

Comment: Re "*It reads a line (or a list of lines).*", Or an entire file, or a paragraph, or a fixed-size block. (This is controlled by `$/`.)

Comment: @ikegami Yes, you can redefine what a "line" is. :-)

Comment: @melpomene I triple chekced I did not forget the `<>` signs, but the `readline` solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Janiaje I've added a few more things that might have gone wrong (but really, you should just post a [mcve] in the first place).

Comment: @melpomene I tried to make one but that is what blew my mind that I could not make one (in that way I might have been able to locate the problematic line). As I wrote in the question I tried to make a small simple script which has the same problem (the questionable lies were copied there) but in a separate file it worked. The original code is in a huge proprietary project so I could not share it, sry.

Comment: Re "*if you're using `<foo>` where foo is anything but a dollar sign immediately followed by an identifier and nothing else*", `<identifier>` (no dollar sign) is also `readline`.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the OP put spaces within the <>. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;
open my $fh , '<' , 'input' or die "$!, stopped" ;
while ( < $fh > ) { print ; }
```

output is:

```
GLOB(0x5603e9c1af48)
```

change

```
while ( < $fh > )
```

to

```
while ( <$fh> )
```

or

```
while ( readline $fh )
```

and the output is:

```
line1
line2
```

which is the contents of the file named input.

Perl is usually tolerant of whitespace and provides helpful error messages,
but not in this case.

tested with perl 5.24.1, from 2017.  I do not know if this is a quirk of
this version of perl, or if this applies to all versions of perl.  I cannot
think of any use for this feature, so I would call it a bug in perl.